# Is it possible to render and style a <title> element from within the <head> of an html document?

Tags: html, title, css

Is it possible to render and style a `<title>` element from within the `<head>` of an html document?

I thought it was impossible to render information from the `<head>`, but the system status page for 37signals.com seems to be doing just that - http://status.37signals.com/.

If you inspect the element at the very top of the page, the text that reads "37signals System Status", you'll see that the part of the DOM that is generating the text is the `<head>`'s `<title>`, and the css is as follows:

```
title {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto;
    max-width: 840px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
    float: left;
    color: black;
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Can someone confirm that the `<title>` info from the `<head>` is indeed what is being rendered?  If so, can someone point to documentation that defines this capability as I have not found any?

I have applied the above css to an html document on my local web server using the same browser (chromium, os x 10.8.5) as the 37signals site was viewed on, yet my file did not display the `<head>`'s `<title>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, making `head {display: block}` along does the trick.

Comment: oh. my. god. Thanks Serge for answering my question.

Comment: @BrianZ By the way, works in Mozilla as well. But I see absolutely no reason to use this feature =)